# VBA code to connect to Oracle Data base to run SQL statements

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I need to connect my Excel file to run a macro that executes select query.

## My sample code is

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Range("A1").Value = "Hiii!"

Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object

Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL, strInput As String


strCon = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;User ID=bis5151XXXXXa1;Data Source=canafpi5467qanfo.iaksedafdqwte.com;Password=iXoXXX8886s55it"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open strCon

strInput = InputBox("Input Desired Name")
Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = strInput
strSQL = "select * from " & strInput & " where rownum<200"
Sheet2.Range("D1").Value = strSQL
'Added the following four lines
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")
rs.activeconnection = cn
rs.Open strSQL
Sheet2.Range("A10").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

=============================================

But my Database doesnt have an entry in the tnsnames.ora file. I also tried giving tns details as data source but am getting TNS failure error.
Could some one please help me to connect my excel to oracle just to run a select statement so that the value is returned to a particular cell in excel.
FYI I already have my ODBC configured.